# using character R function

Tags: r, function

I'm creating a function in R where I'm asking a letter (or a string). Here is an example with a first function:

```
fun.1<-function(a=2,b=3,c=4) return(a+b^2+c^3)
```

and another function using the first one:

```
fun.2<-function(letter.to.test="a",a=2,b=3,c=4){
   if(letter.to.test=="a") {a=0:10} 
   else if(letter.to.test=="b"){b=0:10} 
   else {c=0:10} 
   return(fun.1(a,b,c)) 
}
```

How may I write `fun.2` without the if else functions? In my real code, I have 46 parameters to test, so it's ugly to write 46 if else. Thank you

Comment: You've got a nice answer, but a general comment: spacesinyourcodemakeitaloteasiertoread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More general approach:

```
fun.2 <- function(letter.to.test="a", a=2, b=3, c=4) {
   if (letter.to.test %in% letters[1:3]) {
      assign(letter.to.test, 1:10)
      fun.1(a,b,c)
   }
}
```

Comment: All answers were usefull, but the function I was looking for is `assign()`. And thank also for the *checking function with `%in%`.

Comment: It's almost "general". But you use the argument names in `%in%` with `args` or `formals`

Answer (score 1):

You could substitute the `test` value into a `call` to `<-`. Then evaluate it to change the values.

```
fun.2 <- function(test = "a", a = 2, b = 3, c = 4) {
    eval(call("<-", as.name(substitute(test)), 0:10))
    fun.1(a, b, c)
}

fun.2()
# [1] 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `fun.2`

```
fun.1<-function(a=2,b=3,c=4) return(a+b^2+c^3)

mapply(fun.1, a=1:10, SIMPLIFY = TRUE)
# [1] 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83

mapply(fun.1, b=1:10, SIMPLIFY = TRUE)
# [1]  67  70  75  82  91 102 115 130 147 166
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually it was an example for a function with 46 parameters using 3 others function I created. But maybe, I should give a try to `mapply()`.

Answer (score 0):

You want a `switch` statement.

```
fun.2<-function(letter.to.test="a",a=2,b=3,c=4){
   switch(letter.to.test,
      a = {a=0:10},
      b = {b=0:10}, 
      c = c=0:10} 
   )
   return(fun.1(a,b,c)) 
}
```

Comment: OP would still have to write 46 expressions in switch

Comment: @rawr I made the assumption that the expressions may differ between letters.  You are correct that 46 expressions would still be needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want them all assigned to the same value (e.g., 0:10), try this:

```
fun.2<-function(letter.to.test="a",a=2,b=3,c=4){
  assign(paste(parse(text = letter.to.test)), 0:10)
  return(fun.1(a,b,c)) 
}
```